# Does below code have potential memory leak?

Tags: c++

Sonarqube reports a memory leak for the below code. If we assign the output of `strdup()` to the `char * temp` variable and free the `temp` variable later then SQ does not report any potential memory leak.

```
class A 
{ 
  public: 
  string name;
}; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    
  A a;
  char * str = "abcdef";
  a.name = strdup(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No it does not have potential memory leak, it has actual memory leak.

Comment: It is amazing how match unrelated code is added into this question. Why there is a class `A`? Why assign string literal to `char *` (which should not compile). All can be replaced with `main() { strdup("abcdef"); }`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this code has a memory leak.  `strdup()` allocates dynamic memory that must be `free()`'d, eg:

```cpp
int main() 
{ 
  A a;
  char *str = strdup("abcdef");
  a.name = str;
  free(str);
  return 0;
}
```

However, there is no reason to use `strdup()` in this case, as a string literal can be assigned directly to a `std::string`:

```cpp
int main() 
{ 
  A a;
  a.name = "abcdef";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[strdup at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup):

> `char * strdup( const char *str1 );` Returns a pointer to a null-terminated byte string, which is a duplicate of the string pointed to by str1. **The returned pointer must be passed to free to avoid a memory leak.**

So - yes, you have a memory leak.